# Game based on speech recognition

Tags: game, speech-recognition, voice-command

Due to repetitive stress injury I want to limit my use of keyboards and mice. Are there any games which are based solely (or almost entirely) on speech recognition?

I would prefer strategy or role-playing games. And I am fine with either Windows or Linux based products.

Comment: Here is a different kind of non-keyboard/mouse solution.  https://www.leapmotion.com/  I know it is not voice recognition, which is why I did not put in in the answers area.

Comment: [*There Came an Echo*](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/iridiumstudios/there-came-an-echo-0) is a voice-controlled real-time strategy game, scheduled to be released later this year. As far as I can judge from this [gameplay video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOzMKEmpuMU), you’d only have to move the map/camera with keyboard/mouse, while all other commands are via voice (a log of what you said is shown in the top right corner).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to play games without using the mouse, I highly recommend using a hands-free mouse. I personally use [SmartNav](https://superuser.com/a/435266/116475) on Windows (also available on Mac but I haven't tried it there): I use it all the time when using the computer and it works just as good as a mouse. To perform mouse clicks I use the dwell clicking software provided by SmartNAV.

With this, you should be able to play any mouse-only games if it's okay to click is ~0.5 second instead of clicking immediately. Also, if you need to perform another mouseclick than left-click, you have to first click in the dwell clicking software to indicate that the next mouseclick be another type. You could also define a voice command to take care of that, which I haven't done yet (because SmartNav dwell kicking software cannot be used with shortcuts, and Sikuli has issue working with the SmartNAV dwell clicking software's window, so you probably would have to switch to another dwell clicking software) but I really should one day. So far I have been waiting for SmartNav to add shortcuts, a feature that I asked for years ago and should stop waiting for even though they say they would add at some point.

Now if you need to use the keyboard, the best hands-free solution I am aware of is defining voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking Professional (if not Professional you won't be able to define advanced voice commands). A [Dragon Gaming Speech Pack](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-pc/add-ons/index.htm) (non free, Windows) is available, which I haven't tried, but since most commands in your case would be keyboard stokes should be straightforward. One issue is that there is a small recognition lag (say 0.5 to 1 second), which you should be able to reduce a beat by switching to the command mode:

[image]

So any game that would be okay to play with given those conditions could be played without any mouse and keyboard. I would say that many RTS/board/turn-based games should be okay, but most FPS games won't work well.

---

Misc:

- If you investigate this solution, please let me know how it goes, I've always wanted to try more seriously hands-free gaming but haven't found the time yet.
- I created a [Speech recognition SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75192/speech-recognition?referrer=84okvnxOb2UqQRo_of3bPg2). Nobody really seems to care (many computer users like to brag about their WPM speed, and when they get RSI just give up), but using speech recognition for playing was something I had in mind to discuss there.
- [Replacing the computer mouse](http://francky.me/publications.php#mouse2012)
- [Awesome game for disabled gamers!](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/18q3mt/awesome_game_for_disabled_gamers/)

Answer (score 1):

The  episodic adventure game [Bot Colony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bot_Colony) was designed to be used through speech interaction.

> The player communicates with the game by speaking into a microphone, and the game uses speech-to-text software to interpret and react to the spoken words. Before beginning the game, a player is usually required to build an acoustic profile and train speech-to-text, unless typing is preferred.

- Microsoft Windows
- [non-free](http://store.steampowered.com/app/263040/) (~10 USD as of now)
- [Bot Colony : Gameplay Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIkL2GanQrU)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a game that I know using speech recognition.

**[The Howler](http://www.howler.com/)**, it's a strategy game which uses gravity, tension, and wind currents to get your hot air balloon to its destination. You use microphone to control the hot air balloon from its origin to its destination. About the game:

- The game is not free but it's cheap (USD 1.99 on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/306040/)).
- It's available on Windows.
- Check the demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/embed/jolcjHcUDMM?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque).

Answer (score 0):

The RPG [Stardew Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardew_Valley) has a non-official open source mod,  [StardewSpeak](https://github.com/evfredericksen/StardewSpeak), which is users to play the game by voice.

Demo: https://youtu.be/vXgCY8GqfIk