# How to code with voice recognition?

Tags: software-development, c#, speech-recognition, accessibility

Over the years of long nights with poor posture, programming I've got pretty bad RSI. I'm also very interested in voice recognition in general.

I would like a way to be able to program/code (c# as a bare minimum) using my voice.

I've found https://code.google.com/p/dragonfly/ which seems to be able to get close, I'm not yet sure if it will do C# though.

What packages can provide this functionality?

Comment: Closely related, but not focused on C#: [Voice/Speech recognition software for programmers](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2882/903).

Comment: (Also this might interest you: [game based on speech recognition](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10610/903).)

Comment: I check back here every couple of days and sooner or later someone will have a great answer for this question, and I will be able to program without ever lifting a finger again! muwahahah!

Comment: I'm also closely following any new program / solution to code with voice recognition but I fear we have to be patient to get a 100% voice solution :/

Answer (score 2):

This does not *currently* answer the question, but I have been working on a personal project since 2011 for this very purpose. While it isn't finished yet, I estimate it to be completed (and by completed, I mean ready to be used - but probably needs a lot of testing with many different accents) within the next month (give or take a little).

In its current state, I am able to speak-out an entire app (a small app - for testing purposes). Let's take this app for example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello.");
        }
    }
}
```

The way you would 'write' this app using voice, would be to say it like this:

> Namespace ConsoleApplication 2. Class Program. Static void Main takes
>   1 parameter called args, of type string array. Inside Main, say Hello.

I have no plans to support any other languages in the near or distant future, but when the source is released, I would love to see other languages being supported. I am trying extremely hard to prevent the need to *say* any symbol names, because they totally break the normal flow of speech and make it much more time-consuming and difficult to voice-code. This is the main reason for only working on one language; it's just too time-consuming. And I need to be able to get support for one language right, before I even bother with another.

I didn't plan on 'releasing' the program, since it was made to fill a need of my own, but I just came across your question so I might as well release it. I have setup a GitHub repo for it, and the very second I can see that it is reliable-enough to be released, I will push to my repo and upload the binaries.

The repo can be found at: https://github.com/SE505/SpeakSharply

I'll also keep an eye out to see for any changes in this question and I will update this answer. I'd love to see some new answers (and software).

Comment: I was waiting for the answers to roll in but it hasn't happened yet. Thank you for your contribution :)